# ROracle Connection on Worker Nodes // Automated reporting with R Markdown

Tags: r, oracle, foreach, doparallel, roracle

I am running into several distinct problems while trying to speed up some automated report generation for a large dataset. I'm utilizing R + markdown -> HTML to generate a report, and loop over ~10K distinct groupings for the report accessing the data from Oracle.

The system is comprised mainly of two parts

1. a main script
2. a markdown template file

The main script sets up the computing environment and parallel processing backends:

```
library(ROracle)
library(doParallel) ..etc
....
cl <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, con<-dbConnect(db,un,pw)) ##pseudocode...
```

Here the first issue appears to arise. R throws an exception stating the connections on the workers are invalid BUT when I monitor live sessions on Oracle they appear to be fine...

Next, the main calls the loop for report generation.

```
foreach(i=1:nrow(reportgroups), .packages=c('ROracle', 'ggplot2', 'knitr') %dopar% ##...etc 
{
    rmarkdown::render(inputfile.Rmd, outputfile.html, params=list(groupParam1[i], groupParam2[i], etc)
}
```

If I run the foreach loop sequentially i.e., %do% instead of %dopar%, everything seems to work fine. No errors, then entire set runs correctly (I have only tested to ~400 groups, will do a full run of all 10k overnight).

However, if I attempt to run the loop in parallel, invariably 'pandoc' throws an error #1 in converting the file. If I run the broken loop multiple times, the 'task' in the loop (or cluster, not sure which task refers to in this context) which causes the error changes.

The template file is pretty basic, it takes in parameters for groups, runs an SQL query on the connection defined for the cluster worker, and utilizes ggplot2 + dplyr to generate results. Since the template seem to operate when not through a cluster, I believe the problem must be something to do with the connection objects in the cluster nodes from ROracle, although I don't know enough about the subject to really pinpoint the problem.

If anyone has had a similar experience, or has a hunch about what is going on, any advice would be appreciated!

Let me know if I can clarify anything...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved using a variety of hacks. First, main loop was re-written to pull data into local R session instead of running SQL within the markdown report. This seemed to help cure some of the collisions in connections to the database, but did not fix it entirely. So, I added some tryCatch() and repeat() functionality to the functions which queried data or attempted to connect to the dB. Highly recommend anyone having issues with ROracle on a cluster implements something similar, and spends the time to review the error messages to see what exactly is going on.

Next, in the issues with pandoc conversion. Most of the problems were solved by resolving a join to a depreciated table in the SQL (old table lacked data for some groups, and thus was pulling in no rows and the report would not generate). However, some issues still remained where rmarkdown::render() would run successfully, but the actual output would be empty or broken. No idea what caused this issue, but the way I solved it was to compare filesizes of the reports generated (empty ones were ~ 300kb, completed ones 400 + ) and re-run the report generation after the cluster was shut down on a single machine. This seemed to clean up any of the last issues.

**In summary:**

Previously: reports generated, but with significant issues and incomplete data within.

**Fixes:**

For the cluster, ensure multiple attempts to connect to dB in case of an issue during the run. Don't forget to close connection after grabbing data. In ROracle, creating the driver, i.e,

```
driver <- dbDriver("Oracle")
```

is the most time consuming part of connecting to a database, but the driver can be reused with multiple connections in a loop e.g.,

```
##Create driver outside loop, and reuse inside
for(i in 1:n){
    con <- dbConnect(driver, 'username', 'password')
    data <- dbGetQuery(con, 'Select * from mydata')
    dbDisconnect(con)
    ...##do something to data
}
```

is much faster than calling

```
dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), 'username', 'password')
```

inside the loop

**Wrap connection** 
/ sql attempts inside a function which implements **tryCatch** and **repeat** functionality in case of errors

**Wrap calls to rmarkdown::render()** with **tryCatch** and **repeat** functionality and log status, filesize, filename, filelocation, etc.

--Load in logfile created as above from **rmarkdown::render** calls, find **outlier file sizes** (in my case, simply Z-scores of filesize, filter those with < -3) to identify reports where issues still exist. Do something to fix them rerun on a single worker

Overall, ~4500 reports generated from a subset of my data, time on 4 core i5 @ 2.8 Ghz is around **1 hour**.  Total number of 'bad' reports generated is around 1% of the total.